# Edit details: "suggested [time period] ago" shows approved time, not suggested

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, suggested-edits, revisions-list, timestamps

I just approved a suggested edit, and I noticed the time given in the "**edited ... ago**" link under the post shown was only a few seconds, so it was clearly referring to the approval time. I guess there's sense in that, but then it could be misleading.

But then I clicked through to the edit details and saw that the time in the "**suggested ... ago**" link also shows the time it was approved, rather than suggested, and that seems wrong to me.

[image: Time shown is when it was approved, not when it was suggesteed.]

Not a big deal but I figured there's no harm in mentioning it.

Comment: I do think it makes more sense to base the revision time on the approval, so perhaps switching the link text to "edit approved" would work?

Comment: @Tim: that occurred to me too, but I thought it might seem incongruous with the name of the person who made the actual edit being shown right below it. As if it were saying John Buchanan approved the edit.

Comment: Funnily enough, when you click the "suggested" link, then you see "proposed ... ago" with the correct timestamp of the edit suggestion. So "suggested" and "proposed" seems to be not the same `:-)` See also [Suggested edits history for editors implies the resolution time, but provides the proposal time](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87997) for a related issue.

Answer (score 2):

In the edit history, it will always list the actual time the edit was approved and went into effect (and it should). The suggested link in the edit history is meant to provide a way to view the suggestion page and to indicate that it was an approved suggestion rather than a normal edit.

Ultimately, in the edit history, **no one cares what time you *suggested* the edit**. It's completely irrelevant there, because those changes **weren't actually visible** on the question yet. Technically, the post wasn't edited at that time. You didn't edit the post until it was approved, and your activity history will actually list the suggestion you made and the revision of the post as two separate events under suggestions and revisions, respectively.

I agree the text there can be slightly confusing for those who don't understand what it means. Perhaps it could say "approved" or something, but I personally don't see any urgent need to change it.