# Difference in the timing of suggested edits

Tags: discussion, bug, suggested-edits, timestamps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Edit details: “suggested [time period] ago” shows approved time, not suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103188/edit-details-suggested-time-period-ago-shows-approved-time-not-suggested)

Whenever I suggest an edit, it is reviewed within a minute; sometimes it is reviewed in 3/5 minutes. When my suggested edit is approved, the timing in revision page is different from the timing in my activity. For example, see [this revision](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/145597/revisions). It shows I suggested the edit at 2012-09-01 05:15:30Z, while in [my activity](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/187824/hims056?tab=activity) it shows 2012-09-01 05:09:44Z. Also, in the [review page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6363), it shows 2012-09-01 05:09:44Z, which is the actual time.

#### The time in revision page

> [image: Revision page]
>
> The time in my activity page
>
> [image: activity page]

So the time is different on the revision page. It shows the time when my suggested edit was approved. This happens in both Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Overflow. Is this a bug or by design?